# Issue Looping Through Charts In A Selected Group

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Hello I am trying to loop through all charts in a selected group and am not having much luck. I am still getting up to speed with VBA and would appreciate any help that you have.

Workflow:
1) I have a set of charts that is grouped together into a array/shape range ( I right clicked all and clicked group)
2) I want to loop through all of the chart objects in the shape range and perform a specific line of code

I have tried to write code that does this if the object is selected but I am having an issue where it doesn't loop through a grouped object. My code is below and any help would be appreicated

```
Sub ChartLooping1()
Dim cht As Excel.Chart
Dim shp As Object
  For Each shp In Selection.ShapeRange
     If shp.Type = msoChart Then
        Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(shp.Name).Chart
        MsgBox shp.Chart.Name
     End If

  Next shp


MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have really played much with Shapes (I did something with Charts however) adding **.GroupItems** after *Selection.ShapeRange* seems to work:

```
 For Each shp In Selection.ShapeRange.GroupItems
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You're welcome :)
Maybe you could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840857/excel-2010-vba-and-listobjects-subtotals-not-updating-on-table-changes)